# Code claims function does not exist only if it is called from html-set onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a very strange issue preventing my code from firing a JQUERY function - but only if the event is declared in an onclick attribute tag within the page's html. If that same function is assigned to an element with a javascript ".click(function()..." event, then the function is called properly and the code doesn't say "This event doesn't exist!", essentially.

I trawled through the internet looking for someone with the same issue, and while there are a lot of questions that look superficially like the issue I am having, none seem to address it exactly.

Here is an example:

```
//Delete an existing exclusion.
$.fn.deleteExclusion = function (idExclusion) {
     document.cookie = idExclusion + "=; expires=; path=/";
     $.fn.buildExclusions();
}
```

If I call this method by saying:

```
$("#someButton").click(function(){
     $.fn.deleteExclusion();
)
```

... then the function exists and is run properly.

However, if I assign this function as follows (created on page load as part of page html):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$.fn.deleteExclusion();">Some Button</a>
```

... then the function doesn't exist when I click that link.

This does not happen for one of my company's websites, which uses ASP.NET .aspx page structures. However, I am working on a new MVC application, which is where this behavior is occurring.

I am stumped, frankly. Right now, I am not sure what else to provide code-wise to demonstrate, without probably overdoing it with unnecessary details. Please let me know if you need additional code to help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a workaround. To get this working, we added:

```
//Set onclick events for delete exlusion anchor tag buttons created dynamically.
$(document).on("click", "a.deleteExclusion", function () {
    $.fn.deleteExclusion($(this).attr("id").replace("delete", ""));
});
```

This created the onclick event on page load, but applied it to elements as they were created. It allowed elements created in our cshtml file initially, along with dynamically created html elements, to have a working click event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include Jquery

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$.fn.deleteExclusion = function (idExclusion) {
     document.cookie = idExclusion + "=; expires=; path=/";
     $.fn.buildExclusions();
}
});
```

Comment: Hi Paul,

Thanks for taking the time to answer! I do have that though.

I tried the following:
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

and 

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

and I also tried the version you just gave me.

Comment: Also, I tried adding a $ no conflict to see if I had a different version somehow conflicting or something else that was trying to define $. No luck.

Comment: Can you check if you are getting errors in console, you can do this by right clicking inspect element console. If you see any red we need to fix that before we continue

Comment: I am! "Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.deleteExclusion is not a function" from V2:1 where V2 is the .cshtml file name. It throws it into an anonymous script.